# Creating my own Sub-Menu / Parent in the Admin/Config menu

Tags: 8

Is it possible to create my own Parent / Sub-Menu in the Configuration tab in Administration?

Every resource I find seems to give an example of the yaml file placing a link under the Development menu, with ***system.admin_config_development***, but I want one in (for example), ***system.admin_config_MYMENUNAME*** .

Example of current yaml file (hello_world.links.menu.yml) :

```
hell_world.admin:
  title: 'Hello module settings'
  description: 'example of how to make an admin settings page link'
  parent: system.admin_config_development # want this to be system.admin_config_MYCUSTOMMENU
  route_name: hello_world.content
  weight: 100
```

Answer (score 5):

Just thought it would be easier to show a basic example that has both parent and submenu item in the mymodule.links.menu.yml.

Right now both links goto the same place (as I had to pick a default for the parent item, since I didn't have a admin page that lists all my custom links yet ... and also since having "route_name: <nolink>" did not work for the parent menu item even though some peeps said it worked for them [Note: using Drupal 8.6.12]):

```
mymodule.parent:
  title: 'My MainMenu Link'
  parent: system.admin_config
  description: 'Custom main config menu item under the Admin->Configuration menu.'
  route_name: mymodule.form
  weight: 100

mymodule.parent_child:
  title: 'My Submenu Link'
  parent: mymodule.parent
  description: 'This is the sub-menu item for my custom config form.'
  route_name: mymodule.form
  weight: 101
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this parent route: **system.admin_config** (/admin/config)

See example from Drupal core.

```
system.admin_config_search:
  title: 'Search and metadata'
  route_name: system.admin_config_search
  parent: system.admin_config
  description: 'Configure site search, metadata, and search engine optimization.'
  weight: -10
```